# Один код javascript для двух одинаковых id

Tags: javascript

Не подскажете, как сделать так, что бы javascript применялcя к  двум блокам (gentags)? А то, на данный момент, все работает только на первом блоке. Заранее спасибо
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLveco02/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="gentags">
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
</div>

<div id="gentags">
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #100e17;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;  // IE 10+
      overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;  // Firefox
}

#gentags {
        width: 100%;
      padding: 0 10px;
      overflow-x: auto; /**/
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .item {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 75%;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 10px;
      background: red;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function() {
    const slider = document.getElementById('gentags');
    let isDown = false;
    let startX;
    let scrollLeft;

    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      isDown = true;
      slider.classList.add('active');
      startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
      scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      isDown = false;
      slider.classList.remove('active');
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      isDown = false;
      slider.classList.remove('active');
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      if(!isDown) return;
      e.preventDefault();
      const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
      const walk = (x - startX) * 1; //scroll-fast
      slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
      console.log(walk);
    });

        function scrollHorizontally(e) {
            e = window.event || e;
            var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
            document.getElementById('gentags').scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener) {
            // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
            document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
            // Firefox
            document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
        } else {
            // IE 6/7/8
            document.getElementById('gentags').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
        }
    })();
```

Comment: `id` в одном документе, может быть только уникальным

Comment: поменяйте `id` на `class`. Ну и соответственно в js и css `#` на `.`

Comment: Да, поменял getElementById на getElementByClassName и вообще 
 ничего не работает - https://jsfiddle.net/sLveco02/1/

Comment: @PigHead `getElementByClassName` возвратит массив всех элементов

Comment: что-то это стало очень популярным вопросом в последнее время, за последнюю неделю уже, наверное на 4-й вопрос натыкаюсь, где используется несколько id на странице, хотя за предыдущие несколько лет на SO не помню, чтобы хоть раз на такой вопрос натыкался

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="gentags">

document.querySelectorAll('.gentags').forEach(slider => {
  slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    this.isDown = true;
    this.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
  });
  ...
});
```

Comment: Перетаскивание работает, спасибо. Но как  быть с скроллом?

Comment: @PigHead Хм, тоже переделать на индивидуальные элементы с классом `gentags`.

Comment: у меня не получяется никак